# Python3 saving JSON with unicode single quote

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, unicode, ascii

I know this has been asked before on Stackoverflow and on other sites but I cannot seem to be able to save a JSON file using escaped Unicode characters (Python3). I have read a lot of tutorials.

What am I missing? I have tried a lot of things but nothing works. I have also tried encoding/decoding in UTF-8 but I am obviously missing something.

Just to be clear, I have managed to get it working for other characters like й (0439) but I am having trouble with a single quote being encoded..

If I have the following dict:

```
import json
data = {"key": "Test \u0027TEXT\u0027 around"}
```

I want to save it exactly as it is in a new JSON file, but no matter what I do it always ends up as a single character, which is what is encoded in Unicode.

The following 2 blocks print the exact same thing: {"key": "Test 'TEXT' around"}.

```
print(json.dumps(data))
```

```
print(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Is there any way to keep the Unicode string literal? I want to have that very string as a value: "Test \u0027TEXT\u0027 around"

Comment: The thing this JSON is generated by an external source, so when I import my own data, it might crash as it could possibly be unable to work with single quotes as is.

Comment: Any tool that claims to support JSON must be able to deal with both `"Test \u0027TEXT\u0027 around"` and `"Test 'TEXT' around"`. The two variants are equivalent. If you want to enforce `\u0027` notation, you'll have to write and register a `JSONEncoder` subclass with your own implementation for serialising JSON strings. Or use `str.replace()` on the result of `json.dumps`, but that's very ugly.

Comment: Yes, the replace method is ugly but would be fine for my needs (very specific in this case). I still have not managed to get it working, even with raw strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are describing has nothing to do with JSON. This is simply how Python 3 handles strings. Open the shell and write:

```py
>>> "Test \u0027TEXT\u0027 around"
"Test 'TEXT' around"
```

If you do not want Python to interpret the special characters, you should use raw strings (or maybe even byte sequences):

```py
>>> r"Test \u0027TEXT\u0027 around"
'Test \\u0027TEXT\\u0027 around'
```

Reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binaryseq

Comment: No, of course not. See the reference to get a better understanding of the concept: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: Oh, of course. What I'm trying to show is that OP may be concerned about the wrong thing (json dumps vs escape sequences in python).

Comment: I see that I was focusing on the wrong thing, I get that I need to work with raw strings but it still seems to be a kludge as it seems to be adding an extra backslash to my string.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does. This is the only way you can both store the value as a string and prevent the escape sequences from being interpreted.